# Ship dates of simultaneous projects in fogbugz

Tags: fogbugz

I am currently working on two projects, and I am using Fogbugz to keep track of my cases. My question is: if I enter one month worth of estimated work for each project, will Fogbugz estimate that the ship dates for the two projects will be TWO months from now?

Note: there's a discussion [here](http://support.fogcreek.com/default.asp?fogbugz.4.23133.11) but I don't know if it's still relevant. I'm not even sure I understand it correctly hehehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to merge my two projects into one. I then created an area for each project. So while before I had two projects,

- Project A
- Project B

I now have one project with two areas,

- Project: Company

  - Area 1: Project A
  - Area 2: Project B

The ship date for this one project is about two weeks later from the original ship dates before the projects were merged. I guess this confirms that FogBugz disregards any time spent on other projects when calculating the ship date of a project.

Another way I could have worked around this situation is to retain the two projects but change the '% time spent on FogBugz tasks" in the work schedule to 50%.